# rqt_ on a remote machine?

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running roscore and a couple of nodes and dynamic parameter servers on machine A.
I want to modify the parameters from machine B by `rqt_reconfigure` (ROS and rqt packages are installed on this machine) . How can I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281183/rqt_-on-a-remote-machine?/) by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 249 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1- On both machines: connect to the same network.
2- On machine B: set the environment variable

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI = http://machineA-hostname:11311
```

3- Run the rqt_stuff as usual.

---

Originally posted by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) with karma: 249 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-01-30**:
Glad you got it solved. Note that connecting remote ROS Masters can be problematic, so you might want to go through [Networking](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) in addition.

**Comment by [mohsen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33074/mohsen/) on 2018-01-30**:
Thanks! It's working fine for now but I think using ROS on a network with multiple machines could use more tutorials on wiki.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-01-30**:
You're welcomed to contribute to making such a tutorial then!